# jquery setting hidden input value not working as expected in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html-input

Continuing adopting my code to work with IE...

I have a hidden `div` containing a form to edit some information.  When the user selects the item to edit, this div is shown and the fields are populated with the information for the item.  That divs (in simplified terms) looks like this:

```
<div id="editform">
<form action="" method="post" id="qform" name="qform">
    First param: <input name="field1" id="field1"/> <br/>
    Second param: <input name="field2" id="field2"/> <br/>
    ...

    <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid" value=""/>

    <img id="submit" src="..." alt="..." title="..." />
</form>
```

I use jquery to set the values into the fields.  My function for opening up the editing div looks something like this:

```
function edit_item(item_id) {
    item = get_item(item_id);    //this will return a JS object
    $('#field1').val(item.property1);
    $('#field2').val(item.property2);
    ...
    $('#qid').val(item_id);
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        alert($('#qid').val());
        $('#qform').ajaxSubmit();
    });
}
```

All of this works fine in FF, Opera, Webkit and IE 9, however in IE7 and IE8, I'm having a strange problem.  I can see the `item_id` being set correctly in the `edit_item` function, however as soon as that function completes, the hidden input value (`qid`) gets reset to the empty string.  When the form is being ajax-submitted, the alert shows the value to be an empty string despite it being set correctly.  Interestingly, all other fields are fine.  And it works correctly in IE 9.

What am I missing here?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs are required to be unique in the HTML specification. You have multiples of "#field1". Also, IDs cannot start with a hash mark. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however this is not the problem.  In my real code both are valid: unique ID's and no hash sign - typos when creating simplified code for the question.

Comment: maybe edit_item function was fired once more with wrong item_id parameter? have you tried to add alert(item_id); line to edit_item function?

Comment: @Сергій If that were the case, it wouldn't work in IE9 and other browsers, but it's fine in all of them except IE 7 and 8.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is totally stupid, and it shouldn't be the case, however:

```
$('#field1').val(item.property1);
```

did not work.  Yet

```
$('#field1').attr("value", item.property1);
```

worked fine.  I'm leaving it at that.

Comment: @NullVoid Just rechecked again - the second option works for me in IE 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10.

Comment: @AleksG, +1 from me too. Yes. I did work for me too. Some IE browser cache issues :( but finally worked :)

Comment: Crazy. I just ran into this same issue in Chrome 52 on a Mac. In 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for IE without JQuery in pure JavaScript does not look too complicated:

```
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('value', value);
```

Comment: Wow, why did this work and not the regular el.value = value syntax?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Aleks G's answer, I found out that `value` attribute **must not** be defined implicitly in the hidden element in order to jQuery `.setAttr()` and `.val()` work without issue in IE8.

See here for more details:
[jQuery .val() setter not working?](http://www.codem0nk3y.com/2011/03/jquery-val-setter-not-working/)

Answer (score 0):

I know i am late but i used following workaround since it did not work for me after trying all solutions

```
var id=$(this).data('id');
$('#update_entery_div').append(
                "<input type='hidden' name='id' value="+id+" >"
            );
```