# Setting value of input not working on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, children

I can't seem to be able to understand this, i have this code inside an `each` loop :

```
$('#prices_table tbody tr:last').children().eq(2).val("Y U NO WORK?!");
```

Now the above code does't work, yet if i try setting text or html it does appoint the right and changes the text, however setting the value seems to not work.

Needles to say that the specific element is a text input.

I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654595/jquery-setting-hidden-input-value-not-working-as-expected-in-ie7-and-ie8) question that the author seemed to be able to make it work with addressing the attr of the element, meaning :

```
$('#prices_table tbody tr:last').children().eq(2).attr("value","Y U NO WORK?!");
```

But that didn't work either. I have no errors on my page, any idea what could be the problem?

I should mentioned then the addressed element is being created by clone 1 line above using :

```
$('#prices_table tbody tr:first').clone(true).appendTo('#prices_table').show();
```

In case it matters, and this is the html of the element :

```
<input class="itext product_prices_inputs" type="text" name="prices[]" value="0"/>
```

And my code runs inside a `(document).ready`.

Since much of my code is generated with PHP, this is the outputed HTML of the specific `tr` :

```
<tr style="">
<td>
<select class="iselect pricelist_products_select" name="pricelist_product[]" >
     //very big select
    </select>
</td>
<td class="product_price">85</td>

<td>
<input class="itext product_prices_inputs" type="text" name="prices[]" value="0">
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" class="delete_price">delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i'm setting it on an input.

Comment: Please show the markup.  Are they `<input type='text'>` or `<textarea>`?

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Show the surrounding markup too please -  the likely problem here is not the structure of that `<input>` but how you are traversing to it with `.children().eq()`

Comment: It's complicated alot of the elements are generated with PHP so i can't really provide a fiddle or show much surrounding markup. however @MichaelBerkowski i've tried messing around with the `eq()` it seems to address the right element.

Comment: @eric.itzhak "seems to address" => focus on that. Log the selected element(s).

Comment: how can an "input" be a child of a "tr" tag?

Comment: @ArashMilani that's it. You deserve the right to write an answer.

Comment: Ya! didn't think of that thank you @ArashMilani! please submit it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an input tag as the children of a tr as it's not possible to have any tag other than `th` or `td` inside `tr` tag. you should go deeper in the `DOM` and find that element a level lower.

something like this should do:

```
$('#prices_table tr:last input')
```

to access the inputs inside last row of that table.

Comment: Well that doesn't work but you've pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: I've found a solution that works, please edit your question with the explination of why that didn't work instead of a solution and i'll mark it as an answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Arash Milanis answer made me realize i am trying to set `val()` on the `td` and not it's child. this code worked in the end, since `td` had only 1 child :

```
$('#prices_table tbody tr:last').children().eq(2).children().eq(0).val("Y U NO WORK?!");
```