# How to add integer value from variable to hidden field by jquery

Tags: jquery

I want add the return value from `var Selectedvalue` to hidden field  `id="Branchidhidden"` in its value.

jQuery:

```
function Branch() {
    var Selectedvalue =  $( "#Branchitemtypeid option:selected" ).val(); //The return value is correct 
    $('#Branchidhidden').attr('value', Selectedvalue)
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Branchidhidden" name="Branchidhidden"  value=""/>
```

When I see the view-source value in hidden field is empty.

Comment: can you please post your full code ? I mean the select and options part too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery setting hidden input value not working as expected in IE7 and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654595/jquery-setting-hidden-input-value-not-working-as-expected-in-ie7-and-ie8)

Comment: You need to set the `value` attribute: `.attr('value', Selectedvalue)` This is a duplicate question.

Comment: use `.val(yourValue)` on that input, but remove the `value=""` attribute from hidden input tag

Comment: use PROP instead of ATTR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use PROP/VAL instead of ATTR

```
function Branch() {
    var Selectedvalue =  $( "#Branchitemtypeid option:selected" ).val(); //The return value is correct 
    $('#Branchidhidden').prop('value', Selectedvalue);

    // or val
    $('#Branchidhidden').val(Selectedvalue);
}
```